# Rebase local repo with remote whose history has changed

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

Following this [guide](http://stevelorek.com/how-to-shrink-a-git-repository.html), I shrank our project repository by deleting some heavy files that are in history. This means that the git history has changed. But the problem now is how my other team members can't get the new shrank version of our repo without losing the changes they've made on branches not currently on remote and also without pushing back the deleted history.

The author suggested clone or rebase:

> Anyone else with a local clone of the repository will need to either use git rebase, or create a fresh clone...

A fresh clone would mean discarding all the changes any team member did locally. Therefore, rebase seems like the better option. But how can we go about it?

I was thinking of something like this: (assuming master is the base branch of the new-feature branch, the local branch on developer machine with new work on it, and master had been affected by the history rewrite):

```
$ git checkout master
$ git fetch origin
$ git pull --rebase
$ git checkout new-feature
$ git rebase master
```

confirm all work well then

```
$ git push origin
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That guide is OK (though there are some tricks to improve things, and the cleaning of the repository will go *much* faster with "BFG"—see other StackOverflow postings including those by the author of the BFG).  And, this part is correct:

> Anyone else with a local clone of the repository will need to either use git rebase, or create a fresh clone...

Unfortunately, your suggested rebase steps are wrong.  The actual required steps are a bit tricky.  They become clear only once you understand the ideas behind Git's hashing, commit graphs, and distributing repositories; what you did with `git filter-branch`; and what you can do with `git rebase`.  There's another way as well, using `git format-patch`, to avoid `git rebase` entirely—but you need to *know* just as much to use it.

(When using rebase, we can use `--fork-point`, at least in most cases.  See below.)

#### Background

What `git filter-branch` does is similar in some ways to what `git rebase` does: they both *copy commits*.  The big difference between the two is *which commits get copied* and *how the copies are performed*.

The next thing you need to know about Git commits—you actually already know this, but you need to understand it a bit better—is that each commit is uniquely identified by its *hash ID*.  These are those big ugly `8f60064...` things Git keeps showing you.  Those IDs are *how* Git finds each commit—but there's a key fact about them, which is, they are produced by computing a cryptographic checksum of the *contents* of the commit.  The commit's contents depend on many other things, including both the so-called *tree*—the source code snapshot; you will change this tree whenever you remove a big but unnecessary file—and also the commit's previous, or *parent*, commit(s).

Again, this crypographic hash ID depends critically on the contents of the commit.  At the same time, though, it's *entirely deterministic*: if you give Git the *same* contents, you will get the *same* hash ID.  This is in fact true of all Git's objects, not just commits.  All four kinds—files (called *blobs*), trees, annotated tags, and commits—use the same hash technique, and hashing a bit-for-bit identical file or tree or tag or commit produces the *same* hash as last time.  This means, for instance, that saving a particular version of a file—regardless of how big it is—in *fifty* commits takes *exactly as much space* as saving it in *one* commit.  Once you *change* the file, though, you have a new version, no longer bit-for-bit identical.  Saving *that* one makes a new and different hash, which saves a new copy of the file.  The hash just serves to let Git *find* the object in its object database: you must *know* the hash to get the actual contents.  It's easy to go from contents to hash at any time: just hash the contents.  And, if you *know* the hash, it's easy to *get* the stored contents: they are there in the database (as the value) if the hash is in the database (as the key).

Because the contents determine the hash ID, we can never *change* **anything** about any Git object.  If we were to change even a single bit, and hash again, we would get a new, *different*, hash ID.  This means that we—and Git—can't actually change anything, ever.  We can only *copy* it to a new, slightly different thing.  We make the copy, hash it, and see if the hash is in the database.  If not, we store the copy with its new hash, and now it *is* in the database.

---

When we—or Git—look at a repository as a whole, we can draw a *graph* of all the commits in that repository.  There are lots of different ways to draw graphs, but for StackOverflow postings, I draw them with "earlier" commits on the left and "later" ones on the right.  Each later commit "points back" to its parent earlier commit(s).  With simple linear chains—which make up most of the repository—that gives us something that looks like this:

```
A <- B <- C <- D   <-- master
```

Note how the branch name `master` "points to" the most recent commit, `D` (I use a single letter instead of the big ugly 40-character hash, which works until I run out of single letters :-) ).  Git calls this the *tip* of the branch.  This latest commit "points back" to its *parent* commit `C`; `C` points back to `B`, and `B` points back to `A`.  Since `A` is the first commit ever made, there's no earlier commit for it to point-to, so it doesn't point anywhere.  Commit `A` is a *root commit*, and it stops all the traversal action.

Usually we don't need the internal arrows, so I draw these as:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
    \
     E--F    <-- branch
```

which is a lot more compact, using lines instead of arrows.  But note that here, `E` has `B` as its parent: `E` "points back" to `B`.  Although there is no arrow *head*, you can tell which commit is the parent, and which is the child, from their relative position across the connecting line: children are to the right of the parents, and parents are to the left of the children.

When Git goes to do things with commits in the repository—such as `git log` or even `git merge`—it starts with the *tip* commits, the ones the branch names point to.  It then uses the internal pointers to find each previous commit.  That is, the *names*, `master` and `branch`, just get things started.  Once we do get started, Git uses the internal "connecting arrows" to find all the *rest* of the commits.

Although I've used single letters here, each commit has a full cryptographic-hash ID, and each commit stores the ID of the previous commit.  That's how `D` *can* "point back" to `C`, for instance.  These stored IDs participate in the crypographic hashes, which means `C`'s ID *affects* `D`'s ID.  Equivalently, we can say that `D`'s ID *depends on* `C`'s.  Note, too, that `D`'s ID *depends on* the work-tree snapshot saved with commit `D`.  If `C` or `D` is where the big file is first introduced, and we go to remove that big file, well ... now let's look at how `filter-branch` works.

#### What filter-branch copies, and why this matters

At a base level, before any optimization, what `git filter-branch` copies is, well, *every commit in the repository*.  (More precisely, every commit reachable from the specified branches or other references; with `--all`, this means literally everything, provided we make some pretty safe assumptions, or start with a fresh clone as in your guide.)

As the filter branch is working, the *way* it copies each commit is to first extract it into all its component parts.  Then it runs your filters.  These filters can *change* things (this is the point of the filter after all).

Whatever changes they make, Git must now *re-compute* the hash ID.  If it turns out that the filter did not actually change anything, the new hash will be the same as the old hash—but I'm getting a bit ahead of things here.  That's completely true for files: if you don't change the file, it will retain its old hash.  If you change the file, the new contents will get a new hash.  It's also true for stored trees (snapshots of entire collections of files).  But let's say that we are working with:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
    \
     E--F    <-- branch
```

What Git is going to do is to filter *all* the commits, in some appropriate order.  It will do `A` first, then `B`.  Then it has a choice: it can do `E` and then `F` and then go back to do `C` and `D`, or it can do `C` and `D`, and then go back and do `E` and then `F`.  (In graph theory terms, Git must do a *topological sort* on the graph.)  We don't need to worry about the details—Git takes care of that—but we *do* need to watch what happens as Git copies each commit.

Let's say for simplicity and concreteness that the copies go in letter order (A, B, C, D, E, F).  Let's also say that our filter is "remove huge file".

Now, suppose the huge file is *not* in commit `A`.  Git extracts `A` and applies the filter.  This tries to remove the huge file—but it's not there!  So nothing actually changes.  Git now makes a commit from what's left, and that new commit is *bit-for-bit identical* to the original `A`.  So it gets the *same hash ID*: the copy of `A` *is* `A`.

Git now moves on to commit `B` and repeats this process.  If `B` does not change, its "copy" is still `B`.

Git goes on to commit `C`.  This commit *does* have the big file—so our filter removes it, and Git makes a new commit.  This commit is *no longer bit-for-bit identical*, so it gets a new hash, and is stored in the database as a new and different commit.  Since it's a *copy* of `C`, let's call this commit `C'`:

```
     C'
    /
A--B--C--D
    \
     E--F
```

Now Git moves on to commit `D`.  We're going to copy commit `D`.  Will the copy be bit-for-bit identical to the original?  Well, if we had to remove a file, of course it *wouldn't* be.  But—suppose whoever made commit `C` realized their mistake, and *removed* the big file.  Now the copy might be bit-for-bit identical.  But that would be a mistake, because commit `D` points back to commit `C`.  **We need a commit that points back, not to `C`, but to `C'`!**  So, whether or not commit `D` has the big file, Git makes a different *new* commit.  Our new copy `D'` not only omits the big file—if it was there—but also points back to our copied `C'`:

```
     C'-D'
    /
A--B--C--D
    \
     E--F
```

Git now moves on to copying `E` and `F`.  If they don't have the big files, their copies are just their originals.  If `E` *does* have the big file, its copy is a new commit `E'`, and that forces Git to copy `F` to `F'` too.  If just `F` has the big file, Git can re-use the original `E` but needs a new copy `F'`.

What this boils down to is that *every commit downstream of one that changes, also changes* ("downstream" here means "is a child, or grandchild, or other further descendant").  Once we copy *one* commit, this change bubbles down through the rest of the graph.

If we had to modify `B`, every commit downstream of `B` would also have been copied.  If we had to modify `A` first, then *every* commit would have been copied, giving:

```
A--B--C--D
    \
     E--F

A'-B'-C'-D'
    \
     E'-F'
```

(This is a valid commit graph!  It's composed of two so-called *disjoint* sub-graphs.  Git handles this kind of thing with no problem.)

The last thing `git filter-branch` does is to *move* all the branch names (and, if we have a `--tag-name-filter`, the corresponding tag names as well).  It moves these branches to the copied tip commits.  If we copied just `C` and `D`, this is our final graph, with the labels point back on:

```
     C'-D'   <-- master
    /
A--B--C--D   [abandoned]
    \
     E--F    <-- branch
```

While commits `C` and `D` are actually *still in the repository*, they're now *unreachable*.  They have no name `master` by which to find them.

In order to actually shrink the repository, disk-space-wise, we must now convince Git to throw away the original `C` and `D` (by their hash IDs).  Git would normally eventually do this on its own, except:

1. we don't want to wait, and
2. just in case, `git filter-branch` keeps the original names around as `refs/original`.

Thus, we have to remove those names (as shown in your guide), then use several more "maintenance-y" Git commands to make the expiration happen immediately, instead of eventually.

#### What `git rebase` does

You now understand how `git filter-branch` works, copying every commit ever and sometimes winding up with the copy being bit-for-bit identical and hence actually *the same as* the original, but sometimes having to change every commit "downstream" of a changed commit.  Now that you *do* understand that, `git rebase` seems almost laughably simple.

The rebase command, like filter-branch, *copies* commits.  But, normally at least, it does so by first turning each commit into a *patch*—or more precisely, a patch-with-some-history, or a `git cherry-pick` (these are all subtly different in ways we don't need to go into here).

Look back at the commit graphs we have drawn.  Each commit has some parent(s).  Most commits have just one parent.  A few (one at least) can have *no* parents, and some—what Git calls *merge commits—have two or more parents.

For any commit with just one parent, which is most of them, we can run `git diff` to *compare* the new child commit against its older parent, to see what *changed*.  The output of this `git diff` is a set of instructions: "to change parent commit into child commit, remove these lines and add these other lines."  This is a *patch*.  Since it's now a patch—a set of changes, instead of a snapshot—this patch version of the commit can be applied to a *different* source snapshot.

This doesn't work for merge commits, because they have at least *two* parents.  (I have not drawn any merge commits above.)  So `git rebase` normally just *skips them entirely*.  It also does not work well for root commits; and normally you don't rebase those either (and it does not make much sense in the first place).

By turning each commit-to-rebase into a patch, `git rebase` can copy multiple commits to a *new place* in the graph.  For instance, given:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
    \
     E--F    <-- branch
```

we can copy `E--F` so that the new copies come *after* `D`:

```
A--B--C--D     <-- master
          \
           E'-F'  <-- branch
```

To do this, we tell `git rebase` which commits to copy:

```
git checkout branch   # i.e., end the copy with the tip of branch
```

and which commits *not* to copy:

```
git rebase master     # i.e., *don't* copy commits that are on master
```

and *where to put the copies:*

```
git rebase master     # i.e., put the copies after the tip of master
```

Note that the `<upstream>` argument to `git rebase` does *two things* here, namely specify *what not to copy* and *where to put the copies*.

That works well for most (but not all) regular rebases.  It won't work for us, for two reasons.  One is easy to handle using `--onto`, as we will see.  The other is trickier.

Most Git commands figure everything out by hash ID.  This is true for `git rebase` as well: it knows which commands are candidates for copying, and which are not, by their *hash ID*.  But we ran `git filter-branch` and copied commits to new ones, with *different* hash IDs.  Now, it's true that rebase has some extra smart-stuff in it, to account for some cases of copied commits, but they won't help us enough, as we will see in a moment.

#### Rebasing after filtering

Now, our problem is different.  Someone else—not us—ran `git filter-branch` on some centralized repository and turned our `A-B-C-D` into `A-B-C'-D'`.  We may or may not have `E-F` coming off `B` as well.  But—here's the tricky part—we have *our own* repository, which is *separate from the centralized one*, that has *our own* commits `G-H`:

```
           G--H   <-- feature
          /
A--B--C--D        <-- master, origin/master
    \
     E--F         <-- origin/branch
```

Some clown :-) has done gone and run `filter-branch` on the *central* repository and replaced `C-D` with `C'-D'`.  We now run `git fetch`—**do not use `git pull`**—on that central repository, to pick up their new commits.  This gives us their new commits, and we keep our own.  We now have:

```
           G--H   <-- feature
          /
A--B--C--D        <-- master
   |\
   | \
   |  C'-D'       <-- origin/master
    \
     E--F         <-- origin/branch
```

Note that our own `master` is not touched.  Our own originals of `C` and `D` are still in our own repository too.  Their copies, `C'` and `D'`, are now *added to* our collection, and our `origin/master` has moved to remember their new `master`.  We don't have our own `branch`, only `origin/branch`, but that did not change this time.

What we need to do now is to *copy* our `G-H` commits.  These are on the branch whose tip is named `feature`.  But our `C` and `D` originals are *also* on this branch.  They have the name `master` pointing to them.

#### Here's what's wrong with your command sequence

You suggested that we run `git rebase` on our branch `master`.  (That's what `git pull --rebase` does: it first runs `git fetch`, then it runs `git rebase` instead of running `git merge`).  Let's see what would happen if we did that.

Here's our starting graph, minus `origin/branch` which we don't care about:

```
           G--H   <-- feature
          /
A--B--C--D        <-- master
    \
     \
      C'-D'       <-- origin/master
```

We run `git checkout master; git rebase origin/master`, which is more or less what you suggested with `git pull`.  We say that we want to copy commits that are on `master`—that's based on the current branch, from `git checkout`—while *excluding* commits that are on `origin/master`.  But those are commits `A` and `B`.  So we'll copy `C` and maybe `D`, and put our copies after `origin/master`:

```
           G--H   <-- feature
          /
A--B--C--D
    \
     \
      C'-D'       <-- origin/master
          \
           C''    <-- master
```

Let's talk for a moment about the "smart" part of `git rebase`: it knows not to just blindly trust commit hash IDs.  What it does is turn a bunch of commits into `git patch-id` IDs too.  Without going into a lot of detail, this *may* let `git rebase` avoid copying `D`.  It definitely does not work for `C` though.

Remember where `C'` came from: it was `C` minus the big file.  The removal of the big file breaks the patch ID smartness: Git looks at B-vs-C and B-vs-C' and they look different.  So rebase decides it must copy `C` again, to `C''`.  That *re-adds the big file*.

Whether `D` gets copied to `D''` depends on what was in C-vs-D and what's now in C'-vs-D'.  Maybe it does get copied, maybe it doesn't, but either way, the damage is done: the big file is back!  Just when you thought it was gone!

#### OK, so we don't do that—but what *do* we do?

What we *want* is to copy `G-H`.  Here's where `git rebase`'s `--onto` is helpful—but we need a bit more.

Remember that the `<upstream>` argument to `git rebase` specifies both *what not to copy* and *where to put the copies*.  Using `--onto`, we can tell rebase *where to put the copies*.

We know where to put the copies: they should go after `origin/master`.  So we will add `--onto origin/master`.  The copies will now go after commit `D'`.

As for what *not* to copy: well, that's actually pretty straightforward, **as long as we have not touched our own `master` yet.**  We want to copy commits on `feature` that are not on *our* `master`.  That is, we want to exclude commit `D` and everything earlier.  So, that's what we should give for the `<upstream>`.

That give us our final `git rebase` command sequence:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase --onto origin/master master
```

The `git checkout` says "work on `feature`, i.e., commits ending at `H`".  The second part, the actual rebase command, says "omit commits that are on our `master`, while putting the copies after `origin/master`".

This is the result:

```
           G--H   [abandoned]
          /
A--B--C--D        <-- master
    \
     \
      C'-D'       <-- origin/master
          \
           G'-H'  <-- feature
```

#### Cleaning up

Now there's one thing left to do, once we've copied all the commits we care about.  We must now reset our `master` to match `origin/master`.  To do this, we will use `git reset --hard`:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Note that we do this *only after* we're done rebasing using our saved `master` to make sure we don't copy commit `D`.  The end result of this last `reset` is:

```
           G--H   [abandoned]
          /
A--B--C--D        [abandoned]
    \
     \
      C'-D'       <-- master, origin/master
          \
           G'-H'  <-- feature
```

which is what we want.

#### But wait, what if we don't have our own `feature`?

We had this graph when we did our `git rebase --onto` after our `git fetch` and `git checkout`:

```
           G--H   <-- feature
          /
A--B--C--D        <-- master
    \
     \
      C'-D'       <-- origin/master
```

But what if we had made commits `G` and `H` directly on `master`?  Then we'd have this:

```
A--B--C--D--G--H   <-- master
    \
     \
      C'-D'        <-- origin/master
```

If we are in this situation, our job is substantially harder.  We must figure out which commits were copied, i.e., which commits are `C` and `D` and which ones are `C'` and `D'`.

If we sit down and draw this graph, it's pretty obvious.  But real-world Git graphs are horribly messy.  (That's why we use branch names in the first place: the computer can keep track of the mess for us.)

It turns out that Git's *reflogs* are our savior here.  When we run `git fetch` to pick up `C'-D'`, this moves our `origin/master` from pointing to `D`, to pointing to `D'`.  The reflog entry, `origin/master@{1}`, still points to `D`:

```
           G--H   <-- master, feature
          /
A--B--C--D        <-- reflog: origin/master@{1}
    \
     \
      C'-D'       <-- origin/master
```

This means we can fix up our `feature` branch using the command:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase --onto origin/master origin/master@{1}
```

(though depending on your shell, you may need quotes around the last argument: the shell might try to eat the `{1}` part and do something with it).  In Git versions 2.0 and later, this kind of cleverness is built in to `git rebase` using `--fork-point`, so that you can use:

```
git rebase --fork-point origin/master
```

This works for many cases, and is often the trick to rebasing after an upstream rewrite (whether that rewrite was `git filter-branch` or `git rebase`).

In any case, however you rebase, it's worth inspecting your new "outgoing" commits carefully before pushing.  To check these commits:

```
git fetch origin
git log -p origin/master..feature
```

(assuming your `feature` is eventually going to get pushed to `master`).

#### Using `git format-patch`

I mentioned above that you can use `git format-patch` instead of `git rebase`.  This may be more comfortable for some, because this gives you a chance to inspect each patch, and you can extract your work as a bunch of patches, then re-clone the original repository (rather than updating your existing but now outdated clone, from the filtered one).

We know that `git rebase` turns each to-be-rebased commit into a patch.  We can just do that ourselves.  The command to turn some commits into a patch is `git format-patch`.

Let's say we have our branch `feature`, based on our `master`, in our repository.  We know someone has filtered the central repository, and we don't want to get the filtered repository yet (or we've already cloned it separately elsewhere).  What we want now is to produce each `feature` commit, those coming after our `master`, as a patch, so we just run:

```
git format-patch --stdout master..feature > /tmp/as-a-patch
```

Now we can view the file to see what commits we have and what they do.  This is basically the equivalent of running `git show` on each commit.

Once we have inspected the patches and determined that they are the right ones, we can go to a new clone of the new, filtered repository and create a new feature branch:

```
git clone <url>                  # clone the filtered repo
cd new-clone                     # switch to the new clone
git checkout -b feature master   # make a new feature branch
git am /tmp/as-a-patch           # apply the patches
```

This stuff is meant for emailing patches from one account to another, hence the name `git am`: **a**pply **e**mail.

Since we never mix the old, pre-filtered clone with the new, post-filtered clone, *and* we carefully inspect our "email" patch file, there's no danger of accidentally re-introducing the big file.

Comment: This answer was awesome.

Comment: By the way, something I didn't mention: in Git versions 2.0 and higher, `git pull --rebase` defaults to adding `--fork-point` logic, so it actually *will* work fairly often. The problem is that it's not entirely consistent about this, and `--fork-point` depends on reflog entries, which do expire. (And, I think there are bugs in it in several Git versions.) It's much safer and better to examine your commits manually here, or use the `--format-patch` method. Note that if you have merges to bring in from a private repo, you must re-do them yourself: there's no good workaround for that.

Comment: I just realised that even after pushing to remote, both the new and old history exist. It looks wiered.
@torek

Comment: Yes: a local repo that has not been filtered and cleaned-out still has the old commits. To get rid of them you must do the same kind of thing you (or the filter-er) did in the other repository: ditch any old references, expire reflogs, and garbage collect items (or wait for them to be cleaned up over time). Git is built to *keep* data, not to toss it out. :-)